# Making ten api calls through a loop

Tags: python

An API I want to use limits requests to 10 items. I want to download 100 items. I am trying to write a function that makes 10 API, using their offset functionality to make it possible. I figured a loop would be the proper way to do this.

This is the code I have, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_key = 'THIS_IS_MY_KEY'
api_url = 'http://apiurl.com/doc?limit=10' # fake url
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}

for x in range(0, 10):
    number = 0
    url = api_url + '&offset=' + str(number + 10)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    x = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
    x = x['data'].apply(pd.Series)
return x
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `number * 10`?

Comment: No, I (believe) I meant number + 10. Since the API limit is 10 documents, I wanted to make a pull, then the next pull is offset=10, then the pull after than was offset=20, etc.. etc..

Comment: how does number get incremented?

Comment: You should try adding `number += 10` to the end of your for loop. Also, you are reassigning values to x every single loop, so you are only returning the last value of x. Is this your intention?

Comment: Should you be using `x` as your loop variable and as your dataFrame?

Comment: i think you want str(number + x).  Then increment number by limit at loop end. the x = assignments confuse me, you should use a different variable name on the last two lines of the loop.

Comment: You can't have a `return` statement outside a method; and even if you had a method definition, it would return the last `x`, since you overwrite it in each iteration of your loop. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You are also using x as your loop counter and as your data frame - which i think is not good practice - although your code might still work because of  the way that the for loop works.  A better is to use the step parameter in the range call - as demonstrated below. It is also not clear what you are expecting to return - are you wanting to return the last offset you fetched - or the the data frame (since your code re-uses x in 3 different ways it is impossible to determine what you intended - so I left it as it is - although I am pretty sure it is wrong - looking at the panda API)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_key = 'THIS_IS_MY_KEY'
api_url = 'http://apiurl.com/doc?limit=10' # fake url
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}

for offset in range(0, 100, 10): # makes a list [0, 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
    url = api_url + '&offset=' + str(offset)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    x = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
    x = x['data'].apply(pd.Series) 
return x
```

Answer (score 0):

what result do you see?
try

```
url = api_url + '&offset=' + str(x * 10)
```

Comment: Wouldn't number * 10 mean that the second request was offset=100, and the third request be offset=1000?

Comment: @Anton, sorry, thought `number` was `x`. you just need to make sure it's 0, 10, 20, ..

Answer (score 0):

The variable *number* never change, since it is set to **0** at the start of the loop.
I think you means this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_key = 'THIS_IS_MY_KEY'
api_url = 'http://apiurl.com/doc?limit=10' # fake url
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}
number = 0

for x in range(0, 10):
    url = api_url + '&offset=' + str(number + 10)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    x = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
    x = x['data'].apply(pd.Series)
    number += 10

return x
```